# Function to check if the row of a matrix contains only zeros

Tags: python

My intention was to create (without the use of any module) a function which would index all zero rows of a matrix inside a list, here is the code I developed:

```
    def check0(self):
    L = []
    for i in range(0, self._m):
        for j in range(0, self._n):
            if self[i, j] == 0:
                if i not in L:
                    L.append(i)
    return L
```

However at this point the function indexes the row as soon that it detects a zero in it, and I do not manage to find an additional condition for this to stop. Would anyone please have a solution?

Comment: Can you provide the possible output what you are expecting with a test case.

Comment: You should tell what the variables in the code are. What does self._m and self._n hold?

Comment: Can you show whether your matrix class inherits from something, or how you implement `__getitem__`? If `self[i]` returns a whole row, it simplifies things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it would add a row if at least one element of the row is zero. This would be a solution:

```py
def check0(self):
    L = []
    for i in range(0, self._m):
        for j in range(0, self._n):
            if self[i, j] != 0:
                break
        else:
            L.append(i)
    return L
```

Here I am using the `for else` statement. The `else` clause is executed if the `break` statement inside the `for` is not reached, which only happens if all elements of the row are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your previous questions deal with the same matrix class, you seem to store the data in a list of lists. In that case you can simply do

```
def check0(self):
    return [i for i, row in enumerate(self._matrix) if not any(row)]
```

0 has a falsy value, so `any(list_of_only_zeros)` will return False.

If you wanted to implement the `any()` functionality yourself, it'd look like the following

```
indices = []
for i, row in enumerate(self._matrix):
    contains_nonzero = False
    for elem in row:
        if elem != 0:
            contains_nonzero = True
            break
    if not contains_nonzero:
        indices.append(i)
```

Which is similar to the `for else` suggestion from the other answer. In this case the `for else` is a bit more succinct, since it saves you two lines not having to toggle the `contains_nonzero` flag.